# Не растягивается флекс-элемент и флекc-контейнер

Tags: css, css3

можно ли сделать без js чтобы блок с классом elem2 занимал всегда половину высоты контейнера, а блок elem1 растягивался и растягивал контейнер. Сейчас при увеличении блока elem1 начинает сжиматься блок elem2.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.elem2 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="elem1">elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1 elem1</div>
    <div class="elem2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CSS существуют проблемы с определением высоты элемента относительно родителя в процентах, так как Вы загоняете алгоритм отрисовки в цикличность и тупик.

Ведь высота родительского блока заранее неизвестна и определяется суммарной высотой содержимого. Но одновременно с этим, Вы хотите, чтобы высота содержимого определялась как половина от высоты родителя (которая заранее неизвестна). Нет точки отсчёта.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, т.е. данное можно сделать только с помощью js?

Comment: Получается, что так

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение!

Comment: @hgtYer, если ответ помог, можете пометить его решение или проголосовать. Скриншот: http://bit.ly/30r5V5b

Comment: см. мой ответ ниже - может, пригодится...

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с комментарием @hisbvdis.

Можете попробовать вот такой симулякр:

```css
/* visual */

.container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

.item {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.elem2 {
  -height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.elem1 {
  background-color: coral;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.elem2 {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* needed */

.item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: inherit;
}

.elem1 {
  display: grid;
  height: 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.elem2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="elem1">
      <textarea>Drag me</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="elem2">elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 elem2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```